# Bitbucket Server: how to automatically merge pull-reqs from a branch pattern and require approval for all other branches?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

How can I set an rule in Bitbucket Server such that all pull-requests from branches that match a pattern (e.g. `foo*`) are automatically merged if the pull-req has 1 successful build and all *other branches* must have both 1 successful build and a minimum approval count?

E.g.:
I want pull-requests from `foo*` to `master` to be automatically merged if the pull-request has 1 successful build (no approvals necessary). So pull-requests from `foobar` and `foobaz` to `master` should be automatically merged after the pull-request has 1 successful build.
Also: pull-requests from all other branches to `master` must require 1 successful build and approval from at least 1 reviewer.

---

What I have tried:
I have tried various combinations of Default Reviews and Workzone > Approvers and Workzone > Merge rules, but the rules appear to end up being additive, and therefore not achieving the desired result as stated above.